# What happens if my stripe count is set to more than my number of stripes

Tags: io, parallel-processing, lustre

I have a doubt regarding Lustre file system. If I have a file of size 64 GB and I set stripe size to 1GB, my number of stripes become 64. But if I set my stripe count as 128, what does the Lustre do in that case?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are missing considering the details like number of OSTs while thinking about this. I will be more elaborated on this because I have seen confusion about striping in many. Please bear with me.

So in case of file of 64GB with stripe_size=1GB; stripes of 1GB are 64 but not the stripe_count. We can have any no. of stripes depending upon the file size and stripe_size, but not the stripe_count which is dependent on OSTs. Here is small experiment, I have 2 OSTs and creating 64 MB file with stripe_size=1M(default)...

```
/dev/loop0 on /mnt/mds1 type lustre (rw,loop=/dev/loop0)
/dev/loop1 on /mnt/ost1 type lustre (rw,loop=/dev/loop1)
/dev/loop2 on /mnt/ost2 type lustre (rw,loop=/dev/loop2)
ashish-203@tcp:/lustre on /mnt/lustre type lustre (rw,user_xattr,flock)
[root@ashish-203 tests]# lfs df -h
UUID                       bytes        Used   Available Use% Mounted on
lustre-MDT0000_UUID       146.4M       17.5M      119.4M  13% /mnt/lustre[MDT:0]
lustre-OST0000_UUID       183.1M       25.2M      147.7M  15% /mnt/lustre[OST:0]
lustre-OST0001_UUID       183.1M       25.2M      147.7M  15% /mnt/lustre[OST:1]

filesystem summary:       366.1M       50.3M      295.5M  15% /mnt/lustre
```

Now I create a file foo with -c -1(stripe on all OSTs)...

```
[root@ashish-203 tests]# lfs setstripe -c -1 /mnt/lustre/foo
[root@ashish-203 tests]# lfs getstripe /mnt/lustre/foo
/mnt/lustre/foo
lmm_stripe_count:   2
lmm_stripe_size:    1048576
lmm_pattern:        1
lmm_layout_gen:     0
lmm_stripe_offset:  1
    obdidx           objid           objid           group
         1               2            0x2                0
         0               2            0x2                0
[root@ashish-203 tests]# dd if=/dev/urandom of=/mnt/lustre/foo bs=1M count=64
64+0 records in
64+0 records out
67108864 bytes (67 MB) copied, 7.465 s, 9.0 MB/s
[root@ashish-203 tests]# du -h /mnt/lustre/foo
64M     /mnt/lustre/foo
[root@ashish-203 tests]# lfs df -h /mnt/lustre/foo
UUID                       bytes        Used   Available Use% Mounted on
lustre-MDT0000_UUID       146.4M       17.5M      119.4M  13% /mnt/lustre[MDT:0]
lustre-OST0000_UUID       183.1M       57.2M      115.8M  33% /mnt/lustre[OST:0]
lustre-OST0001_UUID       183.1M       57.2M      115.8M  33% /mnt/lustre[OST:1]

filesystem summary:       366.1M      114.3M      231.6M  33% /mnt/lustre
[root@ashish-203 tests]# lfs getstripe -c /mnt/lustre/foo
2
```

So here we can see file 64MB is created and stripe_count is 2 which means data is written to all the 2 OSTs equally.

**stripe_count is equal to the no. of objects in a single file. and each object of the file is stored on different OST.** Hence it is the number of OSTs which is responsible for no. of stripe_count.

Now when you say if I change stripe_count to 128 then you should have the 128 OSTs if you don't then file will be striped only on available OSTs and that will be your stripe_count(if file is created with "-c -1" option).

> But if I set my stripe count as 128, what does the Lustre do in that case?
>
> > So if you have suppose 64 OSTs then lustre will stripe file only on 64 OSTs

Here is small experiment for above theory...

```
[root@ashish-203 tests]# lfs setstripe -c 4 /mnt/lustre/bar
[root@ashish-203 tests]# dd if=/dev/urandom of=/mnt/lustre/bar bs=1M count=64
64+0 records in
64+0 records out
67108864 bytes (67 MB) copied, 7.31459 s, 9.2 MB/s
[root@ashish-203 tests]# du -h /mnt/lustre/bar
64M     /mnt/lustre/bar
[root@ashish-203 tests]# lfs df -h /mnt/lustre
UUID                       bytes        Used   Available Use% Mounted on
lustre-MDT0000_UUID       146.4M       17.5M      119.4M  13% /mnt/lustre[MDT:0]
lustre-OST0000_UUID       183.1M       89.2M       83.9M  52% /mnt/lustre[OST:0]
lustre-OST0001_UUID       183.1M       89.2M       83.9M  52% /mnt/lustre[OST:1]

filesystem summary:       366.1M      178.3M      167.7M  52% /mnt/lustre
[root@ashish-203 tests]# lfs getstripe -c /mnt/lustre/bar
2
```

You can see in spite of setting the stripe_count=4 stripe_count is 2 and data was written only 2 OSTs.

Summary:- Don't confuse stripe_count with no. of stripes.
stripe_count is on how many OSTs you want to stripe your data if they are available and stripes = (file size / stripe_size).

Hope that answers you question...

Answer (score 0):

If the stripe count is set to 128, 64 stripes are utilized out of 128 and rest 64 stripes are left out. Lustre filesystem writes data in round-robin fashion which is necessary while striping. Also to make sure that the rest of the stripes are not left out imbalanced we need to set a property so that the write starts from 65th stripe.